Automatically logout after refreshing page
I'm trying to develop a basic level authorize system but it's logouts after refreshing the page and I don't know why. I'm kind of a beginner so I'm building a minimal project for my company and here I'm stuck at. I can login successfully and my roles are working fine but I didn't understand why that logout after refreshing the page.
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization;
using ProtaTestTrack2.Services;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class CustomAuthenticationStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider
{
    private readonly UserService _userService;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
    private ClaimsPrincipal _currentUser;

    public CustomAuthenticationStateProvider(UserService userService, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _userService = userService;
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        _currentUser = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity());
    }

    public async Task MarkUserAsAuthenticated(string username, string role)
    {
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, username),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role)
        }, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

        _currentUser = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
        
        var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
        {
            IsPersistent = true,
            ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(60)
        };

        _ = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.SignInAsync(
                CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                _currentUser,
                authProperties);
        });

        NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(_currentUser)));
    }

    public async Task MarkUserAsLoggedOut()
    {
        _currentUser = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity());
        await _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(_currentUser)));
    }

    public override Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
    {
        var user = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User;

        if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            _currentUser = user;
        }

        return Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(_currentUser));
    }

    public async Task<string> GetUsernameAsync()
    {
        return _currentUser.Identity.IsAuthenticated ? _currentUser.Identity.Name : null;
    }
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <base href="/" />  
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="_content/MudBlazor/MudBlazor.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />  
    <link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="favicon.ico" />
    <HeadOutlet @rendermode="InteractiveServer" />
</head>

<body>
    <Routes @rendermode="InteractiveServer"/>
    <script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>
    <script src="_content/MudBlazor/MudBlazor.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>

I tried to create new auth templates of mudblazor but didn't work as well.

Does the link useful to you ? It has detailed information about how to maintain-authentication-state in blazor.
